# JavaScript function stops working when page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and one of the functions has started working. 
On my agenda page here: http://staging.chinahiking.cn/agenda/
it used to be that when you clicked the tabs, the upcoming trip would change. I just realized now it has stopped working, and I'm not sure why. What's even weirder is sometimes when I do a hard refresh, and while the page is still loading and I click the tabs, its working again, but when the page is fully loaded it stops working. Here is the JS function:

```
<?php get_header();
$cur_month = date('n');
$month = array(1=>"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
$agenda = get_agenda_by_month();
?>

var $=function(objectId){
    if(document.getElementById&&document.getElementById(objectId)){
        return document.getElementById(objectId)
    }
    else if(document.all&&document.all(objectId)){
        return document.all(objectId)
    }
    else if(document.layers&&document.layers[objectId]){
        return document.layers[objectId];
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};
function tabTurn(presObj, classon, showdiv){
    var pObj = presObj.parentNode;
    var items = pObj.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var n = i + 1;
        var cntDiv = $('location_desc_' + n);
        if(items[i] == presObj){
            items[i].className=classon;
            cntDiv.className = showdiv;
        }
        else{
            items[i].className='off';
            cntDiv.className = 'undis';
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the html:

```
  <div class="monthes">
            <div class="month_list">
                <ul class="month">
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
                    if($i!=$cur_month)
                       echo "<li onclick=\"tabTurn(this, 'on', 'month_desc');\" class=\"off\">$month[$i]</li>";
                    else
                       echo "<li onclick=\"tabTurn(this, 'on', 'month_desc');\" class=\"on\">$month[$i]</li>";
                }?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
          <?php
                for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++):
                    if((isset($agenda[$i]))):
            ?>
            <div id="location_desc_<?php echo $i;?>" class="month_desc <?php if($i!=$cur_month) echo "undis";?>">
```

Does anyone know why this would all of a sudden stop working? And only sometimes work while the page is still loading, but then stop once it's fully loaded?

Comment: you dont have any logic related to navigation in that code example

Comment: I think you're missing a hash in your selector for `cntDiv`. Shouldn't it be `$('#location_desc_' + n);`?

Comment: @Xesenix i added some more code so you can see.

Comment: @dbramwell no that wasn't it

Comment: anything that is in php code will work only after page reload and from what i see `<div id="location_desc_<?php echo $i;?>" class="month_desc <?php if($i!=$cur_month) echo "undis";?>">` this part is responsible for setting correct month after page reload

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using jquery properly. You should be using the `addClass` and `removeClass` functions.

Opening devtools on your site, I can make the page change by running:

```
$('#location_desc_6').addClass("undis")
$('#location_desc_8').removeClass("undis")
```

As a side note, the selectors need to start with # if you are wanting to select elements by id.

If you really wanted to use `className = whatever` then you would need to specify that you want to run on the first item returned by the selector, like:

```
$('#location_desc_6')[0].className = "undis"
```